# Compare two text files, the same points, different description of the points

Tags: arrays, bash, grep, compare, diff

I am dealing with this task.
I have two text files containing list of points (e.g. point 1ABC_AA). Each point has description (bellow point 1ABC_AA is on each line some description, e.g. bellow point line 1 - yellow, line  2 - green and so on). Bellow Each point with description is empty line.

What I need is comparation of these files. To find out what point was deleted, what was added a what was modified = point is the same however description is different. For searching added or deleted points I used grep. It worked well. However I am dealing with troubles when description of points is different. Please see example of points bellow:

**file1:**

point 1ABC_AA

*yellow*

green


point 2ABC_BB

red

blue

**file2:**

point 1ABC_AA       #(the same point, different description)

*black*

green


2ABC_BB

red

blue

***My desired output should be list of points where description was modified but the name of points is the same. Something like example bellow.***

Modified points:

**file1:**

point 1ABC_AA

yellow

green


**file2:**

point 1ABC_AA

black

green

Any idea how to do it in Bash?
Thank you

Comment: Is it correct that `2ABC_BB` in file2 misses the word "point"?

Comment: Maybe this already helps: `diff <(awk -v RS=  '{$1=$1}1' file1) <(awk -v RS=  '{$1=$1}1' file2)`

Comment: You are right. File2 should have point 2ABC_BB, the same like in File1.